# RailsでCSRF対策しているのにMass Assignment対策をする意味

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails等のWebアプリでCSRFとMass Assignmentの両方に対策する必要があるのでしょうか。
CSRF対策さえできてれば、正当なFormからのデータ送信＝Mass Assignment対策不要と考えました。Strong Parametersで全データを無分別にpermitした場合(もちろんCSRF対策は行う)、どんな問題が生じますか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSRF攻撃は悪意を持った人物がわなを仕掛け、そのわなを踏んだ正規ユーザーに普通のリクエストを送らせるというものです。例えば「リンクを踏むだけで特定の文言がツイートされてしまう」といったものです。ですから、正しいページ遷移かどうかを検証します。

一方 Mass Assignment は、ユーザーから送信された値をデータベース等に保存するという処理において、求めていないデータが送られてきても一緒に保存してしまうという問題です。本来ユーザーには書き換えさせない列まで書き換えられてしまいます。

ではページ遷移が正しければ、Mass Assignment が行われる可能性はないと言えますか？関係ないですよね。正当なFormを開いて、ブラウザの開発者ツールでinputを追加して、送信ボタンを押すだけで Mass Assignment を利用した攻撃は成立します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。つまり、ログインしてFormを開けるユーザーがブラウザの開発者ツールでinputを追加して、送信ボタンを押すくらいしか、攻撃手段がないわけですね。ログインユーザー＝攻撃者な場合、問題になるという理解でよいでしょうか。

Comment: @山田太郎 そういうことです。ユーザー＝攻撃者という構図はSQLインジェクション等と同じで、他のユーザーに頼ることなく攻撃者が一人で好き放題できる可能性につながります。ユーザー登録やアクセスが制限されているサイトでは脆弱性は限定的かもしれませんが、一般論としては「対策の必要がない」ことはありません。